# Factorization through Hilbert Space

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

I am working on my Masters thesis which is on the Grothendieck's inequality. My aim is to study its formulation in different contexts starting from commutative case and then covering non-commutative cases (C*-algebra and operator space versions). Currently, I am following the [CBMS notes by Gilles Pisier](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?extend=1&pg1=IID&s1=140010&vfpref=html&r=90&mx-pid=829919) reading select portions as per need.

While working through the C*-algebra case I am stuck at the following point. I have the following two theorems.

The theorem which can be called as non-commutative litte Grothendieck Theorem.

**Theorem 9.4.** Let $A$ be a C*-algebra, $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $T:A\rightarrow H$ be an operator. Then there are two states $f,g$ on $A$ such that for all $x\in A$ we have
$$ \|Tx\|\leq \|T\|(f(x*x)+g(xx*))^{1/2}$$

The second theorem is about factorization of an operator.

**Theorem 4.1.** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces such that $X^*$ and $Y$ are of cotype 2. Then every approximable operator $u:X\rightarrow Y$ factors through a Hilbert space and satisfies $$\gamma_2(u)\leq (2C_2(X^*)C_2(Y))^{3/2}.$$

We recall that if $T:X\rightarrow Y$ factors through a Hilbert space $H$ and $T=AB$ where $B:X\rightarrow H $ and $A:H\rightarrow Y$ then we define $\gamma_2(u)=\inf \|A\|\|B\|$ where the infimum runs over all possible factorizations. Also $C_2(X^*)$ and $C_2(Y)$ are cotype constants of $X^*$ and $Y$ respectively.

Now, using these two theorems we have to prove the following theorem.

**Theorem 9.6.**  Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $Y$ be of cotype 2. Then any approximable operator $T:A\rightarrow Y$ factors through a Hilbert space. Moreover, there are states $f$ and $g$ on $A$ such that for all $x\in A$ we have $$\|Tx\|\leq C\|T\|(f(x*x)+g(xx*))^{1/2},$$ where $C$ is a constant depending only on the cotype 2 constant of Y.

I proceed for the proof in the following obvious way.

**Proof.** Since $A$ is a C*-algebra, then $A^*$ is of cotype 2. Then by theorem 4.1, $T$ factors through a Hilbert space, and $$\gamma_2(T)\leq (2C_2(A^*)C_2(Y))^{3/2}=C\quad \text{say}.$$ Let the factorization of $T$ be $T_1:A\rightarrow H$ and $T_2:H\rightarrow Y$ and $T=T_2T_1$. Then \begin{equation} \|Tx\|=\|T_2T_1(x)\leq \|T_2\|\|T_1(x)\|.
\end{equation} Since $T_1:A\rightarrow H$ we apply theorem 9.4 to get states $f,g$ on $A$ such that \begin{equation}
\|T_x\|\leq \|T_1\| (f(x*x)+g(xx*))^{1/2}
\end{equation} so that \begin{equation}
\|Tx\|\leq \|T_2\|\|T_1\| (f(x*x)+g(xx*))^{1/2}
\end{equation}

Here is the point where I am stuck. How do I show that the RHS part in the inequality is $\leq C'\|T\|(f(x*x)+g(xx*))^{1/2}$, where $C'$ is come constant which depends only on the cotype 2 constant of $Y$.

Another technicality is that I don't want to go in the theory of type and cotype. Instead I am taking theorem 4.1 for granted and that the dual of a C*-algebra is of cotype 2. Rest I am just trying to merge the results well. My guide says that it has something to do with approximable property. But I am not sure of that. I would appreciate if one could show how precisely I should get the constant.

Comment: The $T_i$ are chosen s.t. $\gamma_2(T)=\|T_1\|\cdot \|T_2\|$ and from the open mapping theorem you have from Theorem 4.1 for approximable $T$ that $\gamma_2(T) \le K \|T\|$ for some constant $K$ depending only on the cotype 2 constants.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Johnson. May I get a suitable reference which covers these topics in detail? Or if time permits, can you kindly sketch how to choose specific $T_i$'s so that the product equals the infimum?